# How do avoid duplicating a field in an array push() function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, meteor, push

I have an array that collects statistics of an image when viewed/viewed. When the array is read, it shows the captured information such as the viewed dates by a user, and that particular users _id (generated by `Meteor.user()._id;`). Shown as displayed below:

```
{viewedDate: "Sat Apr 08 2017 23:00:47", viewedBy: "udEnfEmy5DSBvDsSy"}
{viewedDate: "Sat Apr 08 2017 23:01:17", viewedBy: "udEnfEmy5DSBvDsSy"}    
{viewedDate: "Sat Apr 08 2017 23:01:27", viewedBy: "udEnfEmy5DSBvDsSy"}    
{viewedDate: "Sat Apr 08 2017 23:02:37", viewedBy: "udEnfEmy5DSBvDsSy"}
```

As you'll notice there are duplicates in the `viewedBy` field. How do I avoid the duplicates in the `viewedBy` field?

Find below my current code:

```
  var viewStatistics = buyList.find({_id:"kegqdvFHFoQptvJXn"});
  var currentUserID = Meteor.user()._id;        
  viewStatistics.forEach(function(itemName){

  viewStatisticsArray = [,...itemName.viewStatisticsArray];  

  if (viewStatisticsArray.indexOf(itemName)== -1)  viewStatisticsArray.push({viewedDate: Date(),  viewedBy: Meteor.user()._id });  

});
```

In a failed attempt to avoid entering duplicates as `viewedBy` I have also tried the code below which logically makes alot of sense but failed to get the desired effect:

```
if (viewStatisticsArray.indexOf(itemName.viewedBy)== -1)  viewStatisticsArray.push({viewedDate: Date(),  viewedBy: Meteor.user()._id });
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why not just save "udEnfEmy5DSBvDsSy" in a variable, then set the `viewedBy` field to the variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

viewStatisticsArray.indexOf() == -1 won't work because each element of the array is different (the dates are different).

You could do:

```
var viewedByItem = viewStatisticsArray.filter(function(d) {
    return d.viewedBy == itemName.viewedBy;
});
if (viewedByItem.length == 0) {
    viewStatisticsArray.push({viewedDate: Date(),  viewedBy: Meteor.user()._id });
}
```

or if you still want to use indexOf(), you could make a map function to return the viewedBy property of each object:

```
var viewedByPeople = viewStatisticsArray.map(function(d) {
    return d.viewedBy;
}
if (viewedByPeople.indexOf(itemName.viewedBy) == -1) {
    viewStatisticsArray.push({viewedDate: Date(),  viewedBy: Meteor.user()._id });
}
```